# getting error with Google maps API in FLutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I enabled Google maps api, and I added the api to **AndroidManifest.xml** and **AppDelegate.swift**.

And I added to **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="MY_API"/>
```

But even that when I'm trying to run the app and use Google maps, I got **Error getting the google api**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]